# Flutter: ListView.builder's trailing IconButton alters items list without being asked to

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-listview

- I have two identical lists initiated with the same data: freeBooks
  and updatedFreeBooks.
- I am trying to return a ListView.Builder made of elements from the freeBooks List.
- Each ListTile has a trailing IconButton which removes the item from the updatedFreeBooks
  List, but NOT from the freeBooks List.
- YET for some reason pressing the trailing IconButton is also removing the element from the freeBooks list *and updating the ListView* WITHOUT BEING ASKED TO. *WHY???*

How can I ensure that the code doesn't alter the original freeBooks List?
Here's the code sample:

```
                                  child: ListView.builder(
                                      itemCount: freeBooks.length,
                                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                        String novelTitle = novel.title;
                                        return ListTile(
                                          title:
                                              Text('$novelTitle'),
                                          trailing: IconButton(
                                              onPressed: () {
                                                setState(() {
                                                  updatedFreeBooks
                                                      .removeAt(index);
                                                });
                                              },
                                              icon: Icon(Icons.cancel)),
                                        );
                                      }),
```

Comment: How are you initialising freeBooks and updatedFreeBooks

Comment: List freeBooks = [];
List updatedFreeBooks = []; (THEN)
setState(() {
freeBooks = user.fbooks;
updatedFreeBooks = user.fbooks;
})

Comment: Use updatedFreeBooks=List.of(user.fbooks)

Comment: Worked like magic, thank you: can you explain why that was happening?

Comment: Please refer the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use updatedFreeBooks=List.of(user.fbooks)

Objects are passed by reference. When you do list1 = list; and list2 = list;, you're assigning the reference of list to both list1 and list2. So changing the object at that reference will change the data you see at all of these different variables.